# Put a Label in another function generated window

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I solved the problem I asked for in [Put a Label in a function-generated window from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800701/put-a-label-in-a-function-generated-window-from-another-function)

Now, I have another problem on the same script.

```
def window1():
    windowone=Tk()
    button1=button(windowone, command=window2)

def put():
    labeltoput=label(windowtwo, text"text to put")

def window2():
    windowtwo=Tk()
    putlabel=button(windowtwo, text="put label on windowone", command=put)
```

Now, when I click on the Button `putlabel`, I want that the label in the function `put` goes in the `windowtwo`, instead of appearing in the `windowone`.

They're all global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `Tk()` twice in the same program<sup>1</sup>. If you want a window, create an instance of `Toplevel`.

<sup>1</sup>Technically you can, but only when you understand the ramifications. Unless you have a fairly deep understanding of Tkinter, it almost certainly won't behave like you expect it to.

Comment: windowtwo is garbage collected when the function window2() exits.  I would strongly suggest learning classes before Tkinter.  Then you can make windowtwo an instance variable that can been used throughout the class.  And note that you should use windowtwo=Toplevel(windowone) to avoid possible conflicts.

Comment: Example for global variables http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm